# Old samples of magnesium oxide become contaminated with magnesium carbonate. Suggest how this contamination takes place

Tags: redox

Old samples of magnesium oxide become contaminated with magnesium carbonate. Suggest how this contamination takes place.

I don't understand what I'm meant to put for this.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site. Finally, we have an important policy: your questions (especially [homework questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/142/189)), should show your own work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Carbonate contamination in oxides compounds often happens after a certain time and air exposure because of the $\ce {CO2}$ in the air.

For your magnesium oxide it follows the reaction

$\ce {MgO + CO2 -> MgCO3}$

with $\ce {MgCO3}$ being the magnesium carbonate.

A solution to prevent this kind of polution is to keep the oxide in a dessicator or to treat them in a furnace at a temperature around to $500 °C$ wich is the decomposition temperature of most of the carbonate compounds.

Comment: This is the most likely culprit. It also has nice applications for carbon storage and sequestration.